# How prevent excel from transforming values to dates?

Tags: excel

I have European style of numbers (with a comma). However, when I download a file from a website, where dots are used in values and try to open it in excel, some of the numbers becomes a date. I.e. in the file values 18.2 is transformed to 18.feb. How avoid this to happen?

Comment: Can you give a larger example of the input data, how are you "downloading"?

Comment: Probably, this question would rather be answered in [Super User](https://superuser.com/) community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on relevant cell, press Format Cells, and under Category choose Text.
Now the cell is defined as general text, not date as default.

Comment: I tried it, however,  transformed to 43848.

Comment: If it's an exist sheet, try to import the sheet instead of open it. In data tab, click From Text. In final screen of the wizard there is an option for the data format, then pick Text. Easier option: open a new sheet, and paste the values with "Values Only" pasting.

Comment: yes, that is working. thank you